# rebalance individual datanode in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

In hadoop FAQ below:

http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/FAQ#On_an_individual_data_node.2C_how_do_you_balance_the_blocks_on_the_disk.3F

They do give the solution for single datanode imbalace.But I still got question.

Lets assume I have 2 disks: "/disk1" and "/disk2".In each disk, there are data directory "./data".So there are 2 data directory "/disk1/data" and "/disk2/data".And here is the question:

Could I move **blocks and meta pairs** in "/disk1/data/current" to "/disk2/data/current/"?

Comment: why not? did you tried to do and what happens?

Comment: I have tried in a test cluster.But that cluster wasn't healthy originally.So I can't tell it works or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you may move block pairs (The blk_X data file and blk_X_*.meta CRC file) together between disks safely (under the parent *current/* or the proper `Block-Pool ID`'s *current/* directories in any disk), but ensure that the specific DataNode is down at the time of this operation.

You could also move whole subdirectories (you'll find them named `subdirX` (X is a generated number) from disk to disk without concerns, and move blocks from any subdirectory to any other - there is no stickiness with paths to worry about, as long as the DataNode is down.

Answer (score 1):

Will be part of HDFS with Hadoop 3:

- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1312 (added in HDFS 3.0)
- Related - AvailableSpaceVolumeChoosingPolicy - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1804 (added in HDFS 2.1) - this is not default, but we use it in production. Basically AvailableSpaceVolumeChoosingPolicy allows for volumes to become eventually balanced as disks with more space will be preferred when new blocks are allocated.